# Divergence probability of a spreading disease (easy model yet very difficult problem...)

Tags: probability

A square **n*n grid** represents a population of n² individuals.

A **disease** is gradually propagating :

**The first contaminated individual is located at the center of the grid**
(At (n/2,n/2) if n is even. If n is odd, the center isn't well-defined, so we make the assumption he is located randomly somewhere in the 4 cases surrounding the center)

The **nearest neighbours** of an individual are the **four closest neighbours**, that's to say the squares **to the left, to the right, top, and bottom**.

(**So "diagonal neighbours" don't count as neighbours**)

The rules for propagation are :

- Each **contaminated** individual has a **probability p<=1** of
  contaminating each of its nearest neighbour. Basically, if (n,n) is
  contaminated, then (n-1,n);(n+1,n);(n,n-1);(n,n+1) all pass or fail a test :
  if they fail (with probability p), they become contaminated too.
- However, if they **succeed** at the previous test **(with probability 1-p)**, they become **immune forever** to the disease (they can't contaminate neighbours and can't be contaminated by any of its neighbour)

What's the divergence probability p=Pcritical (function of n) at which the disease has a 1/2 probability of contaminating at least one of the individual at the border of the square ?

**To make it clearer, here is how it starts :**

For clarity, we could assign to each square of the grid, the numbers 0 (never exposed), 1 (for contaminated) and 2 (for immune)

At the start, the whole grid is filled with 0's except for the center
The individual at the center is contaminated. (So he is set to 1)
Each of its four non diagonal direct neighbours pass or fail a test.
If p=1/2, a likely case is : two neighbours set to 1 (contaminated), two others set to 2 (immune)

And it goes on and on as new individuals get sick (or find out their immunity)

**If an individual is contaminated, it is for ever. If an individual is immune, it is for ever too. Basically, if a square is set to anything other than 0, it is for ever.**

One easy case :

if n=3, the probability of divergence is p=Pcrit(3) such that (1-p)^4=1/2 so Pcrit(3)=1/2^(1/4) (the only way for the disease not to spread is if all the four neighbours are immune)

This was the trivial case.

Interesting facts :

Pcrit(n) is smaller than Pcrit(n+1)..
(since for the disease to spread through a n*n grid, it has to spread through a (n-1)*(n-1) grid...)

-Numeric simulations show that Pcrit(n) is logarithmic-like

-It grow very quickly from 0.159 (Pcrit for n=3) to 0.55 (Pcrit for n=40) and then slows considerably (0.577 for n=100, below 0.59 for n=200 or n=300 don't remember exactly)

-It is easy to find the exact expression of Pcrit for n=4 too

-It is pretty obvious Pcrit(n) is a solution to *a certain polynome* whose order grow very quickly. (Notice how I found Pcrit for the n=3 case. it works by hand for the n=4 case too, but I haven't been able to compute/program something which gives the polynomial to solve)

**There is a good chance Pcrit doesn't have a closed form. I'd be interested if someone could find the solution through a bizarre yet computable sum or a good asymptotical approximation, or a limit as n->+inf if it converges. Well actually even a convergence proof would be awesome**

This is a very difficult problem, I thank everyone for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an alternative model.  Before any infection occurs, we determine which individuals are susceptible and which are not: each individual, independent of the others, is susceptible with probability $p$.  Then you introduce the infected individual at the centre of the grid.  A susceptible individual will become infected if 
one of its neighbours is infected, an unsusceptible one will never be infected.

Let $S$ be the subgraph of the grid graph induced by the susceptible individuals.  The infected individuals will be the union of the connected components of $S$ containing the neighbours of the initially-infected individual.

This is pretty much the setup for [Site Percolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory).   There is a critical value $p_c$:  if $p < p_c$, then as $n \to \infty$ the probability of infection reaching the boundary goes to $0$, if $p > p_c$ it is bounded away from $0$.